# Using jQuery Validator for Empty Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using the jQuery Validation Plugin to validate some forms, and I'm not able to quite get what I want when using with some inline table editing I'm coding. So I'm hoping someone here can shed some light.

I'm currently trying to validate for an empty or null input field. I can get it to work with the built-in rules such as "required: true" and stuff. But I can't seem to get it to validate the field if there's no data in it.

You can check out this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/RBennett/jz0un0fr/) to see what I mean
(my last attempt was with the 'noempty' validator.addMethod)

What am I missing or overlooking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it with a function like this one to check if number of characters is less than one:

```
function notempty(id){

    var value = $("#"+id).val();

    var len = value.length;

    if (len < 1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up retooling things quite a bit (other things outside my custom rules weren't working 100%), and I think I've now got it working now (I've updated my Fiddle in case it helps anyone else).